# Where to apply these akonadi settings for mysql-server?

Tags: 11.10, mysql, akonadi

I Am using an external mysql-server to work with akonadi. (using KDE4). 
Now I could solve all problems with it, but I still have to apply some settings to the "mysql-global.conf"-file of the server. That's what is suggested for example:

`# wait 365d before dropping the DB connection (default:8h)`

`wait_timeout=31536000`

So I tried to change this setting via the mysql console. 
But it's not reflected anywhere in the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file.

(etc/akonadi/mysql-global.conf seems to have no effect on the mysql-server either!)

My question: Where to put these (or similar) settings to apply them in a way that akonadi won't drop the connection with an external server (globally I guess?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a variable in the mysql console will not update the `my.cnf` - it is reflected only until the mysql daemon exits.

`/etc/mysql/my.cnf` is the correct place to put it though, under the `[mysqld]` heading.

It will be loaded in after a restart, alternatively to do it immediately in mysql console as well (this sounds like what you tried already):

```
SET GLOBAL wait_timeout = 31536000;
```

**Update in response to "doesn't work" comment:**

Quote from mysql.com docs [1]:

> On thread startup, the session wait_timeout value is initialized from the global wait_timeout value or from the global interactive_timeout value, depending on the type of client (as defined by the CLIENT_INTERACTIVE connect option to mysql_real_connect()).

So changing it does work, but you can't see the result in a mysql console session. Try changing interactive_timeout for that.

To see that it is taking effect, use `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES` instead:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout';
```

[1] http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

Comment: Thx! I will fill in all the akonadi mysql settings into the global file and hope (!) that it will not affect other database apps in a bad way ...

Comment: The entry in my.cnf shows no effect at all! When I look at the actual values with SHOW VARIABLES it says it's still 28800! Yes I have restarted the service and even the whole system!

Comment: It does work. Your variable isn't being adjusted because you are an interactive session. You want interactive_timeout for your console session, and wait_timeout for your script.

Comment: See my update to the answer. Can I have my green tick back now please? ;)

Comment: thx, but still it seems that kmail with akonadi is still loosing the connection after 8 hours ...

Comment: Ok, then you probably want to start a new question. You can reference this one, saying you've tried wait_timeout, but ask for other reasons it might be happening - this is going beyond the scope of the original question now.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Edit my.cnf (the MySQL configuration file).**

> **Ubuntu 16.04**

```
 sudo vi /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

> **Debian**

```
 sudo vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

> **Centos**

```
 sudo vi /etc/my.cnf
```

**2. Locate the timeout configuration and adjust it to fit your server.**

```
[mysqld]
wait_timeout = 31536000
interactive_timeout = 31536000
```

**3. Save the changes and exit the editor.**

**4. Restart MySQL to apply the changes as follows:**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```